# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError after installing SmartTarget API extensions

Tags: smarttarget, fredhopper

As part of SmartTarget 2014 I'm installing Fredhopper 7.5 revision 14. Following the instructions [here](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SmartTarget%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-8BDDDAAD-BB27-4150-9121-C3283EA5A0C8)

Everything is fine until step 9.  After I install the API extensions and restart the qserver running on the index server, I see the following in the fredhopper\data\instances\indexer1\log\qserver.log:

`2014-07-25 10:19:49,319 INFO  [main] Starting service Catalina
2014-07-25 10:19:49,319 INFO  [main] Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
2014-07-25 10:19:49,458 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] Deploying web application archive D:\apps\fredhopper\data\instances\indexer1\tomcat\webapps\fredhopper.war
2014-07-25 10:20:23,044 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] Initializing REST SEO extensions...
2014-07-25 10:20:25,580 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.18 11/22/2013 01:21 AM'
2014-07-25 10:20:26,058 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] Instantiated the Application class com.fredhopper.config.RESTConfigurationApplication
2014-07-25 10:20:27,638 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jvnet/jaxb2_commons/lang/Copyable
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1190)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1681)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2521)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2641)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1457)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.MethodList.getMethods(MethodList.java:77)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.MethodList.<init>(MethodList.java:64)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.MethodList.<init>(MethodList.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.modelapi.annotation.IntrospectionModeller.createResource(IntrospectionModeller.java:118)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.getAbstractResource(WebApplicationImpl.java:769)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.getAbstractResource(WebApplicationImpl.java:763)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.createAbstractResourceModelStructures(WebApplicationImpl.java:1590)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1356)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:180)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:799)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:491)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:321)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:376)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:559)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:976)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1653)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons.lang.Copyable
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    ... 53 more
2014-07-25 10:20:27,640 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] Servlet /fredhopper threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons.lang.Copyable
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1190)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1681)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2521)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2641)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1457)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.MethodList.getMethods(MethodList.java:77)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.MethodList.<init>(MethodList.java:64)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.MethodList.<init>(MethodList.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.modelapi.annotation.IntrospectionModeller.createResource(IntrospectionModeller.java:118)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.getAbstractResource(WebApplicationImpl.java:769)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.getAbstractResource(WebApplicationImpl.java:763)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.createAbstractResourceModelStructures(WebApplicationImpl.java:1590)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1356)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:180)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:799)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:491)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:321)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:376)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:559)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:976)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1653)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
2014-07-25 10:20:27,984 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] Deploying web application archive D:\apps\fredhopper\data\instances\indexer1\tomcat\webapps\heatmap.war
2014-07-25 10:20:28,259 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] Deploying web application archive D:\apps\fredhopper\data\instances\indexer1\tomcat\webapps\preview.war
2014-07-25 10:20:32,719 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] Location of FAS Webservice is 'http://localhost:8180/fredhopper-ws/services/FASWebService?wsdl'
2014-07-25 10:20:32,721 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] Web root initialized to '../'
2014-07-25 10:20:32,723 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] SEO root initialized to '../'
2014-07-25 10:20:32,727 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] Deploying web application archive D:\apps\fredhopper\data\instances\indexer1\tomcat\webapps\ROOT.war
2014-07-25 10:20:34,759 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] Initializing SOAP SEO extensions...
2014-07-25 10:20:35,594 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] Deploying web application archive D:\apps\fredhopper\data\instances\indexer1\tomcat\webapps\status.war
2014-07-25 10:20:35,807 INFO  [main] Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8180"]
2014-07-25 10:20:35,821 INFO  [main] Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8181"]
2014-07-25 10:20:35,823 INFO  [main] Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8182"]
2014-07-25 10:20:35,825 INFO  [main] Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8183"]
2014-07-25 10:20:35,827 INFO  [main] Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8184"]
2014-07-25 10:20:35,829 INFO  [main] Server startup in 46529 ms`

There are no errors logged by the qserver before adding the API extensions. Has anyone else seen this? Is this a bug or are the docs wrong here?

Comment: Love the stacktrace ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I currently do not have access to the LiveContent documentation page, so the following information is from the top of my head:

- SmartTarget 2014 installations that use an on-premise installation of Fredhopper are advised to use FAS 7.5.0.16, which is contained in [`fredhopper-7.5-revision-13`](https://extranet.fredhopper.com/downloads/deployment/old/fredhopper-7.5-revision-13.zip) (i.e., not `fredhopper-7.5-revision-14`, which contains FAS 7.5.1.0).
- The error you're seeing is very probably because of an incompatibility with `configuration-management-rest-extension-1.0`. Version 1.0 of this extension is compatible only with FAS 7.5.0.x, whereas version 1.1 is compatible only with FAS 7.5.1.x.
- Thus, you should either:

  1. Use `fredhopper-7.5-revision-13` instead of `fredhopper-7.5-revision-14`.
  2. Use `configuration-management-rest-extension-1.1` instead of `configuration-management-rest-extension-1.0`.

*The first option is very much recommended*, because SmartTarget 2014 was extensively tested with FAS 7.5.0.16.

Comment: Using 7.5-revision-13 resolved the issue.  Thanks!